# checking files as command line arguments in java

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to pass in a text file(input and output files) as the command line arguments inside a `try-catch` block.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
try {
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(args[0]));
} catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
    System.out.println("file does not exist");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("general exception");
}
```

I'm trying to check it by passing a file that doesn't exist but it doesn't seem to work, not even in the general exception. I tried `printStream` as well but nothing really changed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: According to the [FileOutputStream JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File)), `FileNotFoundException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason.` Perhaps the file you are passing in _CAN_ be created, so it is creating it for you. Maybe make the directory read only and see if it still works.

Answer (score 1):

First create a file from text

```
   File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
```

Now check the existence of file using `inputFile.exists()` which will give you `boolean` result `true` if file exists or `false` if doesn't

Plus you also wanna put a check for directories too because `inputFile.exists()` also return `true` if the input Path is of a directory (Folder)

so your check will look like

```
if(inputFile.exists() && ! inputFile.isDirectory()) // ! mean not/complement operator 
 { 
     // yes it's a file
 }
```

Why complement ? cuz we wanna only go further if input represents a file not directory